# Converting array from Spring bean into JSON to reference in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, json, spring, jsp

My aim is to take an array of objects from a Spring bean and convert these to a JSON object to be referenced in a JavaScript. I'm trying to do this all in JSP.

The key components are :

`homePageManager` - Spring Bean which manages home pages for users. I have made this visible as a bean through 'InternalResourceViewResolver'.

`getHomePages` - Method on homePageManager which returns List

`static String UIUtils.toJSONObject(object)` - utility method which converts any object to its JSON equivalent (basically wrappers call to Jackson lib)

I want to take the returned object, convert it to its JSON equivalent, and use this in Javascript for switching between tab pages, all through JSP.

But because of my limited knowledge of JSPs/Javascript etc. I'm tying myself in knots here.

The Javascript part which handles the JSON object afterwards etc. is all working fine as I've 'mocked' the JSON object with static values to test it. It's just the plumbing in between.

I could create a method on `homePageManager` which returns a JSON-version of the tablist, but for me this is wrong as it is not the responsibility of this bean to do that.

One of my latest attempts is :-

```
 <%@ page import="com.adv.e5ahr.jasperserver.ui.utils.UIUtils" %>
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

 <c:set var="tabList" value="${homePageManager.getHomePages()}"/>

 <script>

 var tabs = ${tabList};
 console.log('tabs='+tabs));
 var tablist = <% UIUtils.toJSONObject(tabs); %>; 
 console.log('tablist=' + tablist);
 ...
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that homePageManager is not responsible to create a JSON-version of tablist, then you can always create a bean which does this translation for you.
Before loading this jsp, add the json to the model / session and only do the dom modifications in java script. Having scriptlets on your page is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I've taken this approach ie added a session attribute containing the JSON representation to the session and just referred to it as `${homePages}`